# Calling service inside a loop in Angular giving result the 2nd time instead of 1st

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to call a service in Angular inside a for loop and populate the result inside a Map .

```
map = new Map<string, string[]>();

this.effectivitiesList = this.trimEffectivities.split(",");

for (let effec of this.effectivitiesList) {
  this.hexcodeService
    .GetHexCodeLineValues(
      this.majorModel,
      this.wireNumber,
      this.selected,
      this.trimEffectivities,
      effec
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.hexcodeLineList = data;
    });

  this.map.set(effec, this.hexcodeLineList);
}

console.log(this.map);
```

The problem is i am not getting data the first time this is executed , the result comes as

Map - >

```
VA305 , Array[0]
VA504 , Array[0]
```

But when i call the method for the second time i get data successfully .

```
VA305 , Array[3]
VA504 , Array[3]
```

Does anyone know the reason for it ?

Comment: its because it looks like `GetHexCodeLineValues` is async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make the surrounding function asynchronous by using the `async` keyword. Then you can `await` the result of the hexcodeService. And also replace `suscribe` with `toPromise` to make that possible:

```
async myFunction() {
    for (let effec of this.effectivitiesList) {
        const data = await this.hexcodeService
            .GetHexCodeLineValues(
                this.majorModel,
                this.wireNumber,
                this.selected,
                this.trimEffectivities,
                effec
            ).toPromise();

        this.hexcodeLineList = data;

        this.map.set(effec, this.hexcodeLineList);
    }
}
```